# Add milliseconds to Java date, when milliseconds is long

Tags: java, datetime, date

I am looking for the best way to add milliseconds to a Java Date when milliseconds is stored as a 'long'. Java calendar has an *add* function, but it only takes an 'int' as the amount.

This is one solution I am proposing...

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar timeout = Calendar.getInstance();

timeout.setTime(token.getCreatedOn());
timeout.setTimeInMillis(timeout.getTimeInMillis() + token.getExpiresIn());
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your solution looks *nearly* fine to me, actually. I originally posted an answer going via `Date`, when I hadn't taken `getTimeInMillis` and `setTimeInMillis` into account properly.

However, you're calling `setTime` and *then* `setTimeInMillis` which seems somewhat redundant to me. Your code looks equivalent to this:

```
Calendar timeout = Calendar.getInstance();
timeout.setTimeInMillis(token.getCreatedOn().getTime() + token.getExpiresIn());
```

A generally nicer alternative would be to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) though :) It's generally a *much* nicer date/time API.

Comment: I was using calendar.getInstance() for some implementations but had to give up on it because if the Date comes with TimeZones the calendar will break it.

Comment: @will824: I don't understand your comment at all - `Date` *never* has a time zone associated with it. It's *always* just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: @Jon Actually it should be as you say, but if you check the Date object, it always carries some kind of timezone along with it. Seems Java has had lots of issues with Date manipulation (thats why Joda was born) and this is one of them. That is exactly the reason why I could not use calendars to fix my issue but instead had to resolve to Joda millis manipulation. Of course my issue was very specific and was related to the total seconds that passed from 1/1/1970 that should have been 0 but I was receiving a negative number because of timezone. Using calendars would diminish 1 hour in my case :(

Comment: @will824: No, java.util.Date doesn't have a time zone in it. It really doesn't - what makes you think it does?

Comment: @JonSkeet I know theoretically it does not, but if you debug a Date, it will have 2 properties, one of which will have a value related to timezone. Try to ask a date created in a GMT based server with 1/1/1970 00:00:00 date how many millis it has and surprisingly it will return a negative number. Perhaps is not the Date object itself but the instantiation of it.

Comment: @will824: It's not a matter of "theoretically" - a `Date` object *only* represents millis since the Unix epoch. The implementation has an extra field to cache some values for efficiency, but that doesn't cause any visible behavioural change. Your point about 1970-01-01 is probably due to the time zone *actually* being Europe/London, which was on British Standard Time (UTC+1) at the Unix epoch. Either that, or you've run into http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4832236. Either way, that doesn't support your claim that `Date` has a time zone internally.

Comment: @will842: Note that there's a *static* field which is a `Calendar` which has an associated time zone, but that's basically for conversions - it doesn't affect the data in any particular instance of `Date`.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right but still in practice the behavior product of this bug prevented me to use the suggested solution, therefore I had to use Joda, which provided the milliseconds correctly.

Answer (score 26):

You can also create a date with the current local date plus the number of miliseconds you need to add as Expire time

```
import java.util.Date;

long expiremilis = 60000l; //  1 minute
// Expires in one minute from now
Date expireDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiremilis);
```

Or the same with a calendar

```
long expiremilis = 60000l; // 1 minute
Calendar expireDate= Calendar.getInstance();
// Expires on one minute from now
expireDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiremilis);
```

If you use an existing Date object you can do:

```
import java.util.Date;

long expiremilis = 60000l; // 1 minute
// Expires on one minute from the date object date
Date expireDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() + expiremilis);
```

And with an existing Calendar Object

```
long expiremilis = 60000l; // 1 minute
Calendar expireDate= Calendar.getInstance();
// Expires on one minute from the calendar date
expireDate.setTimeInMillis(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + expiremilis);
```

Answer (score 5):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant createdOn = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_622_800_000_000L);
        System.out.println(createdOn);

        Instant timeout = createdOn.plusMillis(50_000L);
        System.out.println(timeout);
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wzUjbm).

**Output:**

```
2021-06-04T09:46:40Z
2021-06-04T09:47:30Z
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

So, the **solution to your problem** would be:

```
Instant createdOn = token.getCreatedOn().toInstant();
Instant timeout = createdOn.plusMillis(token.getExpiresIn());
```

Check documentation of [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) to learn more about it.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: This is the answer everyone should want. You may want to reinforce the point that a `long` value can be added by demonstrating that `50_000L` and even `5_000_000_000L` can be added.

Answer (score 2):

Calendar is a fairly expensive Date object, and it functionality is not the best.  If you want an all purpose Date object I suggest looking at [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sf.net/) and it has a function which does what you want.

However, a simpler Java Date object is the Date class as @Dubas indicates.

Even simpler for the type of operation you are performing is to use a long.  This is also much faster.

```
long timeoutMS = token.getCreatedOn() + token.getExpiresIn();
```

I use long (in GMT) for all my dates and only use Date for the presentation layer. ie. when you want to convert the date to Text.